# Codeigniter object in session?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, model

I'm starting out with CI and there's something I don't understand.
I'm writing this login page and I'd like to add the users object to the session. How do I do that? The user object comes from my user model..
For a new instance I write:

```
$this->load->model('user_model', 'user');
```

but this won't work:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('userobject', $this->user);
```

Any ideas how this is done?

Comment: It's generally a good practice to avoid storing any model objects in the session (mainly due to loading reasons). The other issue is that when the user visits a page you'll almost always want to check that they haven't been banned or updated in another tab :) I generally just store the user's ID and query the DB on every page.

Comment: Why do you need two instances of the same model?

Comment: so I could compare those objects would be an example... I'd like to add the object to the session, it's more practical imo, but if I can't find how to do it i'll go with th userid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **user Model** create a function for retrieving the user data you want to add to session:

```
function get_user_data($id){
    //example query
    $query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id));
    //might wanna check the data more than this but...
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the **controller**:

```
$this->load->model('user_model', 'user');
$user_data = $this->user->get_user_data($id);
if(!empty($user_data)){
    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think of using an array, I was thinking of an instance from my class. Thank you.

Comment: Saving only the data = you can't use the object's function.

Answer (score 1):

What about serializing your model ;-)

```
$this->session->set_userdata('userobject', serialize($this->user));
```

and then unserialize it when fetching. But, be warn of CI session, it doesn't use the native PHP session, it used the limited size of cookies.