# Custom datatypes on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create custom datatypes to access data more easily when I need it. This would be a simple php class with properties that would store the data I need. For example

```php
class Inventory_line {
    public $prod_code;
    public $prod_name;
    public $fmt_code;
    public $fmt_name;
}
```

Also I intend to store some of this objects in my session data.

I'm trying to achieve this by creating a library with the properties I need and then loading the library and instantiating my class when I need it. My model sets the properties and returning them.

```php
$this->load->library('inventory_line');

$line = new inventory_line();
$line->prod_code = 1;
$line->prod_name = 'Product';
$line->fmt_code = 11;
$line->fmt_name = 'Format';
```

Then my controller saves the object in my session userdata:

```php
$new_line = $this->inventory_model->get_line();
$this->session->set_userdata('new_line', $new_line);
```

But when I try to access to the values stored on my session data (in another controller function) I'm getting an error indicating that *The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object*.

```php
$new_line = $this->session->userdata('new_line');
echo $new_line->prod_name;
```

Q1: How/where should I declare my class to work properly on CodeIgniter?

Q2: Is any of this considered bad practice or could be made in a better way?

**EDIT:** Added code examples and further explained what I'm doing.

**EDIT 2:** Further tests made me discover the error was located where i get the object from session.

Comment: imho to broad - you should @least deliver some portions of your code. Basically you have 2 questions here - first is a philosophical one (not sure if this fits to SO) and second basically means how to avoid the error message _The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object._ - but both of them require some code, in order to help you...

Comment: My bad, I totally forgot! It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution! (reading the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643529/codeigniter-object-in-session/6319416))

I just needed to serialize my object before saving it in my session data to avoid problems retrieving it.